# grep array using keyword array with jquery

Tags: jquery, grep

```
dataArray=[
'red|24|easy|simple',
'red|24|moderate',
'red|24|difficult|hard',
'black|24|difficult|hard',
'black|34|difficult|hard'];
```

I want to find all array items that match all of the words in my text box:

```
'red hard' - matches middle entry
'bl har 3' - matches last entry
'2 b  d h' - matches 4th entry
```

It seems easy to find any 1 matching search term using jquery, but how do I find array items that match all terms as above.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supposing `data` array is a array of arrays, you can use `Array.filter` in the following way.

Firstly, we will split the input string on spaces and using `String.indexOf`, and then we will filter out the entry.

```
var matches = data.filter(function(str){
   return input.split(/\s+/).every(function(elm){
      return str.toLowerCase().indexOf(elm.toLowerCase()) > -1
   }); 
});
```

Now, assuming that there can be more than one match, we are storing the filtered array in `matches`. If you want to take the first result, then just do

```
console.log(matches[0]);
```

Comment: It's not an array of arrays, just a straight array, I thought i needed to use grep rather than filter with arrays?

Comment: @dt192 so is it like `data = ["red|24|easy|simple",...]`?

Comment: Yes exactly as above, I've updated the original post, I edited the code as needed and it works perfectly thanks, is the best way to make it case insensitive to just upper-case the search and keyword string as they are read?

Comment: @dt192 casting it to lower case is slightly better.

Comment: @dt192 glad to have helped :D